# How to log output of a part of a shell script

Tags: ubuntu, bash, script, logging, tee

I'm looking for a concise solution for logging the output of a part of a shell script to a file. Additionally, I still want to be able to follow the life output on screen.

From the man pages of "bash" (builtin `exec`, "Process Substitution") and `tee`, I would have expected the following line (called at the start of the part to be logged) to be a solution:

```
exec >(tee -a logfile) 2>&1
```

Unfortunately, this results in permission errors (sorry, original output in German):

```
$ bash t
t: Zeile 1: /dev/fd/63: Keine Berechtigung
t: Zeile 1: exec: /dev/fd/63: Kann nicht ausführen: Keine Berechtigung
```

The system is based on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS.

How would one protocol a part of a script to a file?

(Collecting the part to be protocoled into a function `f` and using `f | tee -a logfile` would be difficult, since the part stretches across (parts of) multiple functions and I'd like to switch `logfile` in between...)

Thank you in advance.

Comment: what's in your script `t`?

Comment: The shown output appears if `t` contains only the single line `exec >(tee -a logfile) 2>&1`. I also added an `echo "foo"` after that line. The resulting output is exactly the same as above. Apparently, the script terminates immediately after showing the error messages. The file `logfile` is not even created.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I must admit, I'm not completely sure what's your goal... however, the correct synat for your `exec`-trick should be as follows (you only missed a `>`):

```
exec > >(tee -a logfile) 2>&1
```

A simple demonstration:

```
% cat test
#!/bin/bash

echo stdout not logged
echo stderr not logged >&2

exec > >(tee -a logfile) 2>&1

echo stdout logged
echo stderr logged >&2

% bash test
stdout not logged
stderr not logged
% stdout logged
stderr logged

% cat logfile 
stdout logged
stderr logged
%
```

You can see, the `exec` messes up the output by printing the prompt again, when the script reaches that line. So why don't you just log e.g. `stdout`, but not `stderr` of your script?

```
% (echo stdout; echo stderr >&2) | tee logfile
stderr
stdout
% cat logfile
stdout
```

Comment: Thank you very much for pointing out and fixing my syntax error. The correct command is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap the lines you want to log in parenthesis, and then pipe the output through tee:

```
echo this line isn\'t logged
(
  echo this line is logged!
) | tee log_file
echo this line isn\'t logged
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. Unfortunately, it would be difficult to realize for the same reasons that make it difficult to collect the part to be protocoled into a function.